# Error with <input> triggerWord and Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, indexing, triggers

I want to load the page `http://example.com` by typing `trigger` in the `<input>` text box. I made some modifications over time, and at some point it seemed to work but now it doesn't.

How can I make this work? What are some errors that I am missing?

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var input = document.getElementById("idname").focus();
}

$(function() {
  var triggerWords = ['trigger'];
  $('#indexinput').keyup(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < triggerWords.length; i++) {
      if ($(this).val() == triggerWords[i]) {
        window.open("http://example.com/", "_self");
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="idname" type="text" size="20" onkeyup="myFunction(event)" autofocus>
```

Comment: What does `$(this).val()` yield?  Can you be more specific about what isn't working?

Comment: In the code you've provided, you've given us `$('#indexinput')` and `<input id="idname"` - these *clearly* don't match (to a 2nd pair of eyes, of course).   Either it's a simple typo issue or you need to provide the code you actually use.  Have a read of [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You are registering on keyup two times, following code will work. Dont need to register it with javascript if you are mentioning it inline HTML.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="idname" type="text" size="20" onkeyup="myFunction(event)" autofocus>

<script>
  window.onload = function() {
    var input = document.getElementById("idname").focus();
  }
  
  function myFunction(event) {
      var triggerWords = ['trigger'];
      for (let i = 0; i < triggerWords.length; i++) {
        if (event.target.value == triggerWords[i]) {
          window.open("http://example.com/", "_self");
          break;
        }
      }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Depends on what OPs `myFunctionI()` does - from the limited details it sounds unlikely that it redirects the page, but it could have a javascript error.  Anything else and it wouldn't affect the jquery event.  It's not calling "myFunction" twice.  In which case it wouldn't matter anyway because calling it once would redirect.

Comment: It will work as expected on the local machine. But can you tell in what case it will generate error? I might be missing something here.

Comment: My bad - it doesn't "redirect" it opens a new window - so could run twice (and get two windows not none).

Comment: No, it will only run once. how it would run twice?

Comment: I don't tend to use both up the old style `onkeyup=` and jquery events *on the same element* - it's too messy.  If you don't do `onkeyup='return myFunc()'` then the return value of myFunc is ignored and it will continue with any other events.  It's most likely onkeyup runs before .on(keyup) so the 2nd will run, unless there's a js error in onkeyup at which point javascript stops the event and (as far as I know) won't call the .on(keyup).   A js error could be anything such as divide by zero, function not found, console.error

Comment: You said "*You are registering on keyup two times*" - so runs twice, get two windows.  This is not OP's scenario.

Comment: I mentioned that the person who asked the question is trying to do it twice, so I registered it only once, Did you have a look at my code?

Comment: And I mentioned that OP is not trying to do it twice at all.  Did you have a look at my comments?  :P

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong id in the query selector. It says
$('#indexinput') but must be $('#idname').

Consider using the following snippet:

```js
$(function() {
    var triggerWords = ['trigger'];
    $('#idname').keyup(function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < triggerWords.length; i++) {
            if ($(this).val() == triggerWords[i]) {
                console.log('open new page');
                window.open("http://example.com/", "_self");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="idname" type="text" size="20" autofocus>
```

Note that the window.open doesn't work in code-snippets, therefore I added the console.log part.

I also removed this unnecessary part:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var input = document.getElementById("idname").focus();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of `myFunction` and `id` was incorrect

```js
$(function() {
  var triggerWords = ['trigger'];
  $('#idname').keyup(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < triggerWords.length; i++) {
      if ($(this).val() === triggerWords[i]) {
        window.open("https://google.com/", "_self");
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="idname" type="text" size="20" autofocus>
```

Comment: I can understand users with <100 reputation answering "it's a typo"... but really?  Need your daily reputation boost?